# NullReferenceException while accessing ViewBag in Asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I am trying to access the `ViewBag` data in my view as below:

```
<span class="small">@ViewBag.BreadCrumb</span>
```

I am sending that `ViewBag` data from code like:

```
ViewBag.BreadCrumb = topic.Category.CatName + " / " + topic.Name;
ViewBag.TopicID = id;
```

Here, `topic` is the Entity. And I am returning the View using:

```
return View(topic);
```

But, it always send me an exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

In another page it's working very well. Is there any solution?

Edit::

Code of  Action is as follows:

```
Topic topic = db.Topics.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TopicID == id);
ViewBag.Topics = from t in db.Topics where (t.CatID == topic.CatID) select t;
ViewBag.TopicID = id;
ViewBag.BreadCrumb = topic.Category.CatName + " / " + topic.Name;
return View(topic);
```

Edit::

Its shows following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_ieekpj10.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

But in in Immediate windows it shows output:
    ViewBag.BreadCrumb
    "C Sharp Edit / Name- edited to C 12"

Edit:: Stack Trace

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
ASP._Page_Views_Category_NewSection_cshtml.Execute() in e:\OutSourcingStuffs   \OnlineLibrary\src\OnlineLinkLibrary\OnlineLinkLibrary.Web\Views\Category\NewSection.cshtml:12
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +121
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +63
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +100
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext,   TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +177
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +762
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
 System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +74
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +388
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +72
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +303
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +155
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +136
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9688704
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Edit: View

```
@model OnlineLinkLibrary.Models.Section
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "New Section";
}

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading ">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h4>
                New Section
                <span class="small">@ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.BreadCrumb</span>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
        <div class="pull-right"> 
          -- satic htmls are there
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure that `topic` not null?

Comment: @Grundy , not only `topic`, but `topic.Category` too

Comment: Then he would get the exception on the ViewBAg.BreadCrumb =... line not in the view. As I read the question that is the location this happens. The ViewBag seems to be null.

Comment: possibly, ViewBag.BreadCrumb is not getting any value, put a breakpoint there and check.

Comment: Is the exception being thrown in the Controller or the View?

Comment: @rughimire add complete code of action and view, without these is not possible to find the exception reason.

Comment: The exception is being thrown in View.

Comment: I have added full code of the Action

Comment: Have you tried accessing ViewBag.Topics & ViewBag.TopicID in your view ?  Do you get error for them also ?

Comment: @rughimire add view markup also

Comment: @Vaibha and All, If I remove,  
    <span class="small">@ViewBag.BreadCrumb</span> 
it throws exception to ViewBag.Title.

Comment: try to use @ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.Title

Comment: @vaibhav, still not solved using Context

Comment: Edited to provide more details- please help

Comment: try clean project and rebuild

Comment: do you use any 3rd-party libraries in your app?

Comment: I am using EF code first and Angular js and dont think they are making issues. The same things are working in all other views. Just a problem with this. I also clean the solution, still no solution.

Comment: @Grundy, Can you please check the stack trace.

Comment: @rughimire can you provide `NewSection.cshtml`?

Comment: it seems ok. if you remove all calling `ViewBag` from this it work?

Comment: exception only this view? try find defferent from another views that works fine

Comment: can you provide layout also?

Comment: are you sure that you sent the right Model ? I can see you sent model of kind Topic and in your view it expects OnlineLinkLibrary.Models.Section

Comment: @Mohamed , I also tried without sending Model to view. It does not work

Comment: but the view expects the Model !. you should send if you are using it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure by 100% that **the ViewBag is not null** however Visual Studio keeps pointing to that line as null,

then look at the next line of code for the error, the compiler sometimes get confused ;)

This might help a drowning dev.

Comment: Yeah now I am breathing again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest check if topic is null or not.

```
Topic topic = db.Topics.Where(a=>a.TopicID == id).FirstOrDefault();
if(topic != null)
{
  ViewBag.Topics = from t in db.Topics where (t.CatID == topic.CatID) select t;
}
```

Comment: how about second query "from t in db.Topics where (t.CatID == topic.CatID) select t;" have you checked, it is also not null

Comment: In this case I don't think the problem is releted with "@ViewBag.BreadCrumb". Maybe you can focus on layout page or partialView if page has.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is expecting a OnlineLinkLibrary.Models.Section:

```
@model OnlineLinkLibrary.Models.Section
```

But you provide a Topic. Unless Topic is a subclass of OnlineLinkLibrary.Models.Section, it wouldn't work.