# ViewBag Is Producing a Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm passing a ViewModel to the view, along with a few ViewBags. I was re-writing a significant portion of the program, but I didn't touch this page, nor anything related particularly. Suddenly the ViewBag is coming with a null reference exception, which I don't understand because empty ViewBags, in my experience, just come blank.

I debugged, and the date string is being generated. If I change the value to a simple string, "test", it still comes with the exception. Also, I'm using "return View(ViewModel);" to pull the view.

This is the controller. There is more code, but it doesn't affect the issue.

```
public IActionResult Calendar(string DateString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DateString))
        {
            DateString = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            //ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }

        DateTime mDate = System.DateTime.Parse(DateString);

        DateTime dateX = mDate.AddDays(-3);
        //ViewBag.dateX = dateX.ToString("D");
        ViewBag.dateA = "test";
```

This is the view, focused on the error section. The error is specifically "@ViewBag.dateA" which as you can see above in the controller is set to "test".

```
<div>
@*<h5>@ViewBag.dateX</h5>*@
<strong>@ViewBag.dateA</strong>
<table>   
    @foreach (var item in Model.Thr0X)
```

My question is literally how to make the ViewBag work again. I'm hoping someone will look at this and just see a simple error on my part that I'm missing, or something like that.

TBH, I can't see anything wrong with the code I provided, nor the code in general.

Comment: On which line exactly is the `NullReferenceException` thrown?

Comment: Is ViewBag itself possibly `null`?

Comment: specifically the "<strong>@ViewBag.dateA</strong>". I'm also going to add some more controller code in a sec

Comment: @Seth honestly not sure. I don't know why it would be null, I'm clearly assigning a variable string

Comment: According to this link, check the next line of code. It's unlikely that `ViewBag` is null. But there might be a null item in that `foreach` statement. (`Model.Thr0x`, maybe?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062012/nullreferenceexception-while-accessing-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: @MikeHofer that appears to be it. I commented out everything after, and the viewbag works. so now i have another problem...ugh. write out an answer so i can mark you